# Check if 2 vertices are connected in Igraph for R

Tags: r, igraph

what are the functions which check if  two vertices (specified by their name attribute) are connected by an edge (incoming or outgoing or both) or not?
in other words what are the name of the functions `get_eid` and  `are_connected` of  `python` in  `igraph` in  `R` ?

thank you in advance,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an `are.connected()` function in R's igraph library

```
g <- graph.ring(10)
are.connected(g, 1, 2)
# [1] TRUE
are.connected(g, 2, 4)
# [1] FALSE
```

for a list functions in the package, you can try looking at `help(package="igraph")` in the future.

Comment: thanks for the heads up  also, I keep searching the function in [here](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/igraph) with the whole function name in python and not paying attention to the shape of the functions in  `R`

Comment: @academic.user That's for an old igraph version. See http://igraph.org/r/doc/ for the current one